# Is Lucene capable of finding the location of matches within a document?

Tags: lucene

Say I have 100 documents indexed in Lucene. I want to search for the term "American Airlines". Lucene runs the search and gives me back 10 documents that contain the term "American Airlines". I now want to be able to go through each of these 10 documents in my UI, and highlight/scroll to each of the matches automatically. These are all html documents with uniquely id-ed paragraph tags, so I can scroll using something like `http://docurl#p_120` to scroll to `<p id="p_120">American Airlines is a big company.</p>`. But how do I get Lucene to tell me what paragraph the term is in, and exactly where it is so I can highlight it?

Comment: See Lucene's [Highlighter API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about highlighting. You ask how to index a text with subdocuments so that you know the id of the subdocument for highlighting.

imho you have three possibilities. But first of all let me remind you that lucene can use the offset (=position in original text) for highlighting
https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/package-summary.html
and that lucene knows the concept of sub-documents as "blocked child documents" or "nested documents" or "embedded documents".

The tree possibilities:

1. use payloads to store the id of the corresponding subdocument for each occurence of a term.
2. store the offset of each occurrence of a term and be aware at which offset a new subdocument begins. Store the ids together with the corresponding offsets in an extra field and use this to look-up the id for each hit.
3. index the document together with all subdocuments as extra child document in a block. Search with http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/join/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/join/ToParentBlockJoinCollector.html